# X O Game(how i prove that player one(p1) or player two(p2) win if he achive the one of the conditions in (var winBoxes)

Tags: javascript, jquery

how i prove that player one(p1) or player two(p2) wins if he achieve the one of the conditions in (var winBoxes).

```
var counter = 0;
var p1=[];
var p2=[];
var winBoxes = [
        [box1, box2, box3],
        [box1, box4, box7],
        [box2, box5, box8],
        [box3, box6, box9],
        [box4, box5, box6],
        [box7, box8, box9],
        [box1, box5, box9],
        [box3, box5, box7]
       ];

     //Start the click function 
     $('.boxes div').one('click',function(){

    counter += 1;
    if(counter %2 === 0){
        $(this).text('X');
        p1.push($(this).attr('id'));

       }else{

           $(this).text('O');
           p2.push($(this).attr('id'));
       }
    });
```

There is the full code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mona90/pen/eYmpdJd)

Comment: there is the full code on codepen https://codepen.io/mona90/pen/eYmpdJd

Comment: Use SO's widget to create runnable code right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create a separate function to check whether one array is subarray of another.

```
function isSubsetOf(big, small){
  return small.every(x => big.includes(x));
}
```

Then on every change in the box you need to check if any of the arrays in `winBoxes` is subarray of any of `p1` and `p2`. The player for which condition satisfies will win.

```
  if(winBoxes.some(a => isSubsetOf(p1, a))){
    console.log("p1 wins")
  }
  if(winBoxes.some(a => isSubsetOf(p2, a))){
    console.log("p2 wins")
  }
```

Working code here [Codepen](https://codepen.io/maheerali121/pen/xxbXaKw?editors=1111)

Comment: Performance-wise, no need to do extra operations in case p1 array length and p2 array length are still less than 3 items.